# Getting derived member variable through base class pointer

Tags: c++

consider this base class:

```
struct drawable 
{
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) const = 0;

};
```

and this derived class:

```
struct rectangle : drawable 
{
  rectangle(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Vector2f size);
  void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) const;
  sf::RectangleShape body;
};
```

I have similar derived classes for other shapes like circle, line and triangle. I use this function to return shapes based on a string of text I get from a file:

```
drawable * string_to_object(std::string name)
{
    if (name == "RECTANGLE")
    {
        return new rectangle(sf::Vector2f(20,20), sf::Vector2f(5,5));
    }
    else if (name == "BALL")
    {
        return new ball(sf::Vector2f(10,10), 5, sf::Vector2f(0,0));
    }
    else if (name == "LINE")
    {
        return new line(sf::Vector2f(30,30), 10, 5);
    }
}
```

Now in my main I have variables like this to test if it works:

```
auto game_object = string_to_object("BALL");
```

Now the problem is I need to perform actions/checks on the shape's body, which is a member of the derived class that I cannot access from the drawable pointer variables. It's also a problem that the type of the body is not set, it can be a RectangleShape, CircleShape etc so a getBody() function would need a variable return type. How would I go about getting access to the body in a generic way? I've tried templates but I realized that won't work since it's a runtime problem.

Comment: Why do you have that draw() function if you don't use it?

Comment: The behaviour of your program is undefined unless you leak all of the pointers returned by that function (because the destructor of `drawable` isn't virtual).

Comment: adding `else return nullptr;` at the end of the `string_to_object` function would fix it.

Comment: I'm aware of all of this, thanks

Comment: You are using `auto`, so you are clearly using C++11, so you should return a `std::unique_ptr<drawable>` instead of a raw `drawable*` pointer.

Comment: "*I need to perform actions/checks on the shape's body, which is a member of the derived class that I cannot access from the drawable pointer variables*" - what kind of actions/checks exactly? Please [edit] your question to show what you want to do that doesn't work for you. "*the type of the body is not set, it can be a RectangleShape, CircleShape etc so a getBody() function would need a variable return type*" - Make `getBody()` virtual and return `sf:Shape&`, then descendants override it to return their `body` member. `sf::RectangleShape`, `sf::CircleShape`, etc all derive from `sf::Shape`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for that sf::Shape& tip, makes the code a lot cleaner, I can get rid of setters/getters for every body attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are multiple ways how to solve this issue.

1. Re-think your architecture. You could introduce other virtual functions to drawable that every subclass implements. In these functions you'd implement all the checks/actions you need. Since they are implemented in the base class, they have access to the shape's body and since it is a virtual function of the base you can call these functions from the outside.
2. Since your drawable object has a virtual function, you could use RTTI to check the type at runtime and perform a dynamic_cast
   See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI

I'd prefer the first option whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having trouble deciding what functionality is generic to all `drawable` objects, and what is specific to `rectangle`, `ball` and so on. Attributes and methods that apply to all `drawable` objects can be declared within `drawable`, but anything that only applies to a particular kind of `drawable` (like the width and height of `rectangle` vs. the radius of a `ball`) go in the derived classes.

In your example, each of the derived classes *must* implement the `draw` method if you want to instantiate them (because it is declared pure virtual in the base `drawable` class). Each of these specific derived implementations can access the specific attributes of the derived class. So the `rectangle::draw` method can access the width and height, while the `ball::draw` method can access the radius.

Then, when you have a collection of pointers to `drawable` objects (which are really instances of the derived classes) you can simply call the draw method for each of them.

Sorry if this seems overly simplistic - I hope it's clear.